# crudtable crashes when starting from rstudio, Error in if: the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, shiny, crud

I am trying to run this package https://github.com/beerda/crudtable. The package works via live demo link https://beerda.shinyapps.io/crudtable/ on that site.

[image]
Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(crudtable)

# Data Access Object from the CO2 data frame
dao <- dataFrameDao(CO2)

# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  crudTableUI('crud')
)

# Server-side
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  crudTableServer('crud', dao)
}

# Run the shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But when I try to start it from my RStudio R Version 4.2
The program starts but crashes after clicking the `+ New Record` button with the Error:
`Warning: Error in if: the condition has length > 1 1: runApp`
[image]

What does this error stand for and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I could track down the bug. The [`simpleFormUIFactory`](https://github.com/beerda/crudtable/blob/8fd55e6891e3ea9f0eddb277183fa1798bda755f/R/simpleFormUIFactory.R#L19-L40) is faulty. There we test for the type of an attribute like so:

```r
if (a$type == "factor") {
   # ...
}
```

The problem is that with the example dataset the class of column `Plant` is

```r
class(CO2$Plant)
# [1] "ordered" "factor"
```

i.e. it contains **2** elements. With `R 4.2.0` the behaviour of using `if` with conditions of length greater then 1 changed to throw an error instead of a warning ([cf. to the corrsponding section in the `NEWS` for `R 4.2.0.`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html)), i.e. something like

```r
if (1 == 1:2) 1
```

throws an error in `R >= 4.2.0` and was a warning before. (This explains why it works for the demo but not for you).

Having said that, until this bug is patched, you have basically 2 options:

1. Provide your own edit form dialog to avoid the call of `simpleFormUIFactory` in the first place. ([cf. to the help of `crudTableServer` for an example](https://github.com/beerda/crudtable/blob/8fd55e6891e3ea9f0eddb277183fa1798bda755f/R/crudTableServer.R#L42-L53))
2. Make sure all column types in your data frame have exactly one class. Notably transform `ordered` to normal `factor`:

```r
CO2$Plant <- factor(CO2$Plant, ordered = FALSE)
```

P.S.: The package author should replace `==` in the `if` clause by a `%in%`. I will post a comment in your [issue post](https://github.com/beerda/crudtable/issues/5).

Comment: I filed a [PR](https://github.com/beerda/crudtable/pull/6) for this easy fix.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I now use the new version?